# Problem in regular expression isMatch() method in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to match values by using regular expression, but I'm unable to get why following program returning me **false** as output.

```
Regex validateInputString = new Regex("^(\\d)*([a-z[A-Z]])+$");
    Console.WriteLine(validateInputString.IsMatch("343sdf"));
```

Could anyone please tell me?

Answer (score 1):

`[a-z[A-Z]]` does not look very correct. Do you mean `[a-zA-Z]` ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have [character classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx) within character classes. If you want to match either of the letters `a-z` and `A-Z` just use one character class `[a-zA-z]`. E.g.

```
Regex validateInputString = new Regex("^(\\d)*([a-zA-Z])+$");
Console.WriteLine(validateInputString.IsMatch("343sdf"));
```

The code above prints `True`.